# Rails compound key to enforce uniqueness on the pair of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build a toy application and ran across an issue I cannot seem to solve. How do I enforce that a pair of values are unique in a table?

suppose the following schema:

```
  create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "number"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "status", default: 0
  end

  create_table "professors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "status", default: 0
  end

  create_table "sections", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "number"
    t.integer "max_enrollment"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "professor_id"
    t.integer "course_id"
    t.string "room"
    t.index ["course_id"], name: "index_sections_on_course_id"
    t.index ["professor_id"], name: "index_sections_on_professor_id"
  end
```

and I wanted to create a uniqueness constraint in the sections table that the `professor_id` paired with `course_id` must be unique. the only thing I have found in my digging is that you can use the `validates` keyword in the model to enforce the uniqueness of a single field... I also saw that there is a `validates_with` keyword but I cannot find any way of writing a validator to do what I'm looking for. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a unique constraint in your database (Pun in a migration):

```
add_index :sections, [:professor_id, :course_id], unique: true
```

Now also put a validation constraint in your `Section` model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :professor_id, scope: :course_id
```

Now your `professor_id` will be uniquely validated in the scope of `course_id`. Also there will be a unique constraint in your database table.